# extracting holder exponents and singularity spectrum from signal in python

Tags: python, signal-processing, pywavelets

Is there any way of computing the holder exponents and singularity spectrum of a signal using multifractal 1-D wavelet leader estimates?

Matlab has dwtleader: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dwtleader.html#bvfgqrt

Is there any library or existing python implementation that does this similarly?

I have looked at `PyWavelets`, but I couldn't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check this [link](https://github.com/neurospin/pymultifracs). It implements wavelet based multifractal analysis of 1D signals. The code is based on the Wavelet p-Leader and Bootstrap based MultiFractal analysis (PLBMF) Matlab toolbox written by Patrice Abry, Herwig Wendt at all.

Another python package that implements Wavelet p-leader is [MFAnalysis](https://github.com/omardrwch/mfanalysis) and the code is based on the same Matlab toolbox source of previous package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).